# Add SDL Source Code to Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sdl, directory-structure

I am creating an SDL application and to keep things clean and maintainable I would like to put the SDL headers and source code inside a different Visual Studio project, and have it use an appropriate file structure.

SDL did find some interesting ways though, to make this impossible to do with it's current setup. It uses a lot of relative paths and odd configuration options which make it impossible to just copy over the code. (The directury structure would mess up and the setting would be lost) Copying over the whole project doesn't work, also, because of the relative file paths.

How would I go about getting the project into my own solution, in my own directory structure? What options would I need to edit or remove?

Answer (score 0):

Good day. if i get it right - you should **"File->Add existing project"** to add needed project to your solution, then **"Project->Project Dependencies"** to set up your main project to depend of recently added project and **"Project->Project Build Order"** to make sure new project builds first.